# Preview freezes on clicking inside (very small) PDF files

Tags: pdf, preview, performance

I have a bunch of small PDF files, which are a few hundred pages but generally less than 2 MB or so in size. Scrolling is perfectly smooth in Preview.app, but if I **click anywhere inside the PDF, macOS freezes** for a couple seconds. The issue is perfectly reproducible and happens every time for **certain PDF** files.

I'm running the 2016 15-inch MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. This really shouldn't be a hard task for the CPU, so I suspect there's some deadlock going on, like trying to contact some random cloud service. **Does anyone know a fix for this issue?**

Comment: Do you have a tool selected? What happens when you have no tool selected and you use the other type of selection (text vs. rectangular)? Can you upload a sample PDF that does this?

Comment: @timothymh I've had no tool selected, but it does this reliably for both text and rectangular selection, as well as any tool I tried. (It doesn't happen again after the first time, until Preview is quit and reopened.) [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvckd82pmnqgppm/Dyson%20Advanced%20QM.pdf?dl=0) is a link to the smallest file I found that does this, though here the freeze is only for one second. For other files the freeze is up to 5 seconds complete with spinning beach ball.

Comment: Hm, it's not freezing for me. What version of macOS are you running? What happens when you download a copy of the file you just uploaded and try to open it? Is the file on an internal drive?

Comment: @timothymh Yup, still happens after downloading a copy. It's on my hard drive (SSD), not on anything external. I'm on Sierra, 10.12.6.

Comment: Pardon the obvious question, but have you tried rebooting? :) What is the source of these files; did they all come from the same place?

Comment: @timothymh I just rebooted and still get the exact same result! The files are from a variety of places, but it even happens on some files I created myself (for personal notes). The only common link is that all of them contain a lot of LaTeX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66737/discussion-between-timothymh-and-knzhou).

Comment: Can you try this with Preview from Yosemite, ElCap or HighSierra? Might be related to the bugs outlined here: [PDFkit display in macOS Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/295427/251859)